# Php string replace with different values each iteration through a loop

Tags: php, database, while-loop, str-replace

I searched for an answer for this and could not find one. Sorry if there is already one out there. Here's my problem: I have a list of names in a database. Then I have a message that I want to display to each of them. I want to string replace the -user- with the name. Here's my code:

```
$message = "Hello, -user-";
$getusers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getusers)){

    $username = $row["username"];

    //replace -user- with the actual username
    $message = str_replace("-user-", $username, $message);

    echo $username;
    echo $message;
}
```

Now say I have 3 users in my database: dan, bob, and jill.
Here is what it displays:

```
dan Hello, dan bob Hello, dan jill Hello, dan.
```

What I want it to display:

```
dan Hello, dan bob Hello, bob jill Hello, jill.
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure you show us your **real** and **full** code? 2. Please don't use `mysql_*` API anymore it's deprecated

Comment: Just choose another name for your `$message` variable before your while loop and in the str replace call!

Comment: I'd replace everything in the WHILE loop with echo $row['username'] . " Hello, " . $row['username'] ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you have to reset message every time

```
$message = "Hello, -user-";
```

through the loop

Comment: Duh! Thanks! Oh man I should have thought of that

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
$message = "Hello, -user-";
```

into the while loop to start from the same $message each time. Otherwise only first , "dan" is present in message from the first iteration and replacement.